# C# Game Loops and Input

Tags: c#, loops, input, delegates

I am trying to make a simple reusable engine for a game, such as pong. I am having trouble with the timing and inputs.

For instance, using the XNA Game Class, the Update Method is fired 60 times per second. To do that in a class that I make from scratch, would I use timers, or something entirely different?

To clarify on my trouble with inputs, how would I detect a Key event (EX: Key is pressed down)? I think that it has to do with delegates, but I'm not really sure.

EDIT: I am not using XNA.

Comment: why are you not using XNA in the first place? any specific reason not to use it?

Comment: I'm using MonoDevelop so that I can be cross platform. I have platform specific code in external libraries, for drawing and etc. Only Windows supports XNA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use timers with a callback, or even a second thread that is entirely a game loop. I've done it in both Java and C#; I tend to use timers since millisecond resolution is good enough for most games. If you want some (Java) sample code to look at, check out my [rudimentary game engine](http://mechsim.googlecode.com). As for game input... well, check out the sample code. It manages event-driven input and encapsulates it so that the data can be polled. :P

Alternatively, look into [MonoXNA](http://www.monoxna.org). It isn't 100% complete yet, but the 2D parts and basic game stuff (game loop, input, etc) are.

Comment: Thanks for the links... I just skimmed through the Game.cs class of MonoXNA, and I've been able to get an idea of how things work together. I'm going to download the source and read through all of it to understand all that it does (input, timing, etc..). I'm also going to look at your game engine as well. Thanks a lot for the links.

Comment: No problem. You may want to just use MonoXNA directly rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

All you really have to do is just check for keyboard input in your update method. Or, you can create an updateInput method that can be called in your update method.

```
private void updateInput()
{
    KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

    if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

That's essentially it! Of course, this is a rudimentary approach and since you are looking at making a reusable engine, you should look into the [GameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx) class. In XNA, you make components that can be reused throughout different game projects.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using XNA because it is not Cross-Platform. What I was trying to figure out is how to do the timing and input without an existing game library, such as XNA.